# Let Raspbmc play bluetooth audio

Tags: raspbmc, audio, bluetooth

I'm looking to have my Raspbmc setup play audio from my phone using audio over Bluetooth.

In the same way a Bluetooth enabled car audio system would. I have not been able to find anything about this subject (though Raspbmc), though.

Is this possible and how would could I achieve this?

---

Added Dec. 5 2013:

Some more investigation reveals that this has been done and several people have a working setup with bluetooth audio in Raspbmc. It seems that a tutorial or guide has not been written yet, though. Source: http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=9445

It also seems that support is considered directly in Raspbmc. They have a poll to find out which features are most requested where this is mentioned: http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=9675&pid=74999

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! Please do not sign your questions with "Thanks". Consider taking a minute to read the [About Page](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/about). You should give thanks to people by upvoting their answers. If an answer helps you solve your problem please accept it. I have edited your question to improve its quality. Feel free to edit and rephrase as you like.

Comment: You actually want Raspbmc to play music to another audio system using Bluetooth Audio Profile? There are DIY solutions but I am not sure if any package exists to use Bluetooth dongles yet.

Comment: No, quite the other way around. I want Raspbmc to play music that is physically placed on and controlled from my phone. So my phone is the player, and Raspbmc is the "speaker". Like a bluetooth enabled stereo rack that you set to either "CD", "Phono", or "Bluetooth", and then it "blindly" plays whatever it's served.

Answer (score 1):

This instructable shows how to do exactly what you want and works with a standard COTS Bluetooth dongle.  It requires some config hacking, but then again, if you don't want to config hack you'd probably not be trying to do this with a Pi.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, it is not what I want. What I want to to have things happen through Raspbmc so I can utilize my existing media center setup, whereas the webpage you point to builds a headless setup without Raspbmx/XBMC, automatically playing anything that connects with it. That, in itself, is also cool, but I need something non-headless that integrates with Raspbmc. Someone sufficiently knowledgeable would probably be able to build something like that using the mentioned page, but it might seem that no-one has done so and described the process yet.